# Styles in MergedDictionaries not found

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I keep getting a runtime error `StaticResource not found for key` when using a `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary` that's merged by means of `MergedDictionaries`.

### App.xaml

```
   <Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
             xmlns:local="MyApp"
             xmlns:assets="clr-namespace:MyApp.Assets">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <assets:Styles />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                 <Style ...>
                    <!-- other styles... -->
```

### Styles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyApp.Assets.Styles">
    <Style x:Key="Subheading" TargetType="Frame">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DarkSlateGray"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="True"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

### Styles.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Assets
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Styles : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public Styles () { }
    }
}
```

### Page.xaml

```
        <Frame Style="{StaticResource Subheading}">
```

The app compiles correctly -- it just can't find `Subheading` at runtime. If I copy the `<Style>` node directly into App.xaml, it works fine. Can anyone find my incorrect syntax? Or, is there a way, at runtime, to look at Application.Resources so I can figure out where it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an `InitializeComponent()` method call inside of your `Styles` constructor. Do it like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Assets
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Styles : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public Styles()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. I assumed that InitializeComponent() referred to UI components... I stand corrected!